# Why does setting a background color on a tableview change its style?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiview

I have a `UITableViewController` which I initialize with the 'grouped' style.

Why is that as soon as I add either of the following lines, the table view is displayed in 'plain' style with the sticky headers?

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:216/255.0 green:218/255.0 blue:224/255.0 alpha:1.0];
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:216/255.0 green:218/255.0 blue:224/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

Edit: also, the following does the same.

```
[self.tableView setBackgroundView:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it's because I was doing my customization in initWithNibName:bundle, which I thought was the designated initializer. It works fine if I override initWithStyle:

Anyone care to offer a decent explanation?